# using wcf cross domain in svc host

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm following this link :

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2012/02/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html

for implementing cross domain it works in consol application but it doesn't work in svc web wcf service application.

what should I do ?

**Edited :**

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IOrderService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string ProcessOrder();                                                              
    }        
namespace WFS.Services
    {
        [ServiceBehavior]
        public class OrderService : IOrderService
        {
            [OperationBehavior]
            public string ProcessOrder()
            {
                Order order = new Order
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Name = "Laptop"

                };

                DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Order));
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                json.WriteObject(stream, order);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

and configuration code :

```
configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WFS.Services.OrderService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehave">
            <endpoint address=""
                      bindingConfiguration="crossDomain"
                      behaviorConfiguration="enableScriptBehaviour"
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="WFS.Services.IOrderService"/>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4916/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehave">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="mex"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="enableScriptBehaviour">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

and here is json get :

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:4916/Order.svc?ProcessOrder?callback?", null, function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
```

it gives me parser error 200 success

[image: this is error]

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: What error you get? Where it happens?

Comment: 200 is not an error code - that means the request completed.  What leads you to believe it's not working? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

Comment: You're using `$.ajax`, not `$.getJSON`; what is the value of `err` in your function when you're in the debugger?

Comment: no it is parser error for cross domain, it never run any method at the server svc host.

Comment: everything is clear from the image

Comment: it work from consol application very easily

Comment: Hmm....funny...I don't see anything in the image that shows what `err` contains.

Comment: there is no error value for this so that's why I've asked question it is not clear but it is related to cross domain because it works also when they are in the same host.

Comment: Try setting the `cross-domain` setting to true in your AJAX call - add `crossDomain: true,` above `url: .....`

Comment: "jQuery1910028606438255185495_1376421069288 was not called" it is the only message I got now

Comment: Got now when?  After you added the `crossDomain: true` to the AJAX call?

Comment: no I tried this error: function (err, xhr, res) instead of error: function (err) and I watched res value

Comment: Try adding the `crossDomain: true` part.  I think that may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it :

Just add 'Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"' code on the markup of svc service.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WFS.Services.Order" CodeBehind="Order.svc.cs"
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" %>
```

and then I've corrected my config file :

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

adding to attribute to my service class :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "JsonpAjaxService")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

in jquery side I've corrected proccessData:false

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:4916/Order.svc/GetCustomer',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {},
                processdata: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    //it comes here successfuly
                    debugger;
                },
                error: function (err, xhr, res) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Glad you found it, and that you posted the answer. Don't forget to accept it when you're eligible to :)

Comment: Thanks Tim it was hard really